# Zend_Form - multiArray based elements

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-form-element

Using Zend_Form, how would I create form elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="element[0][name]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="element[0][text]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="element[1][name]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="element[1][text]" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use sub forms:

```
$form = new Zend_Form;

// 'element'
$elements = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$form->addSubForm($elements, 'element');
```

And each element is a subform of the 'elements' sub form:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_SubForm;
$element->addElement('Text', 'name');
$element->addElement('Text', 'text');
$elements->addSubForm($element, '0');

$element = new Zend_Form_SubForm;
$element->addElement('Text', 'name');
$element->addElement('Text', 'text');
$elements->addSubForm($element, '1');
```

In the controller you can iterate over elements like this:

```
foreach($form->elements as $element) {
    var_dump($element->getValue('name'));
}
```